# Пунктуация в стихотворении

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация, поэзия

Подскажите, с какими знаками препинания правильно написать эти строки? Почему?

> Над тенью
> Сонных век
> Словно оберег
> Я её храню.

Речь о любви к ребенку. То есть храню любовь.

Answer (score 3):

Эти строки являются частью "Колыбельной", имеющей несколько вариантов — и по тексту, и по пунктуации. Я бы расставила знаки таким образом:
Знай, в счастье и беде
Я отдам тебе
Всю любовь мою —
Над тенью сонных век,
Словно оберег,
Я её храню.

Или таким:
Знай, и в счастье, и в беде
Я отдам тебе
Всю любовь мою.
Над тенью сонных век —
Словно оберег —
Я её храню.

[**словно**, *союз* и *частица*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_677)

1. Союз. Синтаксические конструкции, присоединяемые союзом «словно», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми.

Думаю, что "словно" здесь является союзом (имеет значение *будто, как, точно*), поэтому сравнительный оборот "словно оберег" необходимо выделить запятыми (как авторский вариант — с помощью тире).